Notifications not updating correctly after viewing files in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages project where users can view and manage requests. Each request has a notification badge that should disappear when the user views the files associated with the request. Additionally, this notification should not reappear when the user revisits the page if they've already viewed the files.
However, I'm encountering an issue where the notification badge does not update correctly. Even after viewing the files and updating the database, the notification reappears when the user revisits the page.
Here is the relevant code:
Table Structure:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VisualizacaoArquivo](
    [IdVisualizacaoArquivo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IdRequisicao] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IdUsuario] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DataVisualizacao] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_VisualizacaoArquivo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IdVisualizacaoArquivo] ASC)
);

Requisicao.cshtml.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProcurementSystem.Pages.Request
{
    [Authorize]
    public class RequisicaoModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<RequisicaoInfo> ListRequests = new List<RequisicaoInfo>();

        public void OnGet()
        {
            string userId = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "IdUsuario")?.Value;

            try
            {
                string connectionString = "Data Source=...; Initial Catalog=...; User id=...; Password=...!";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    string sql = @"
                    SELECT 
                        a.IdRequisicao, 
                        a.NomeRequisicao, 
                        b.TipoRequisicao,  
                        a.DataRequisacao, 
                        ISNULL(a.DataConclusao, '') AS DataConclusao, 
                        ISNULL(a.IdUsuarioAtendente, 0) AS IdUsuarioAtendente, 
                        ISNULL(c.Nome, '') AS NomeAtendente, 
                        a.IdUsuarioRequisitante, 
                        d.Nome AS NomeRequisitante, 
                        e.DescricaoStatus,
                        f.Operacao,
                        g.Comentario AS UltimoComentario,
                        h.DescricaoStatusComentario AS StatusComentario,
                        i.DataVisualizacao AS UltimaVisualizacaoArquivos
                    FROM 
                        [dbo].[Requisicao] a
                    LEFT JOIN 
                        [dbo].[TipoRequisicao] b ON a.IdTipoRequisicao = b.IdTipoRequisicao  
                    LEFT JOIN 
                        [dbo].[Usuario] c ON a.IdUsuarioAtendente = c.IdUsuario
                    LEFT JOIN 
                        [dbo].[Usuario] d ON a.IdUsuarioRequisitante = d.IdUsuario
                    LEFT JOIN 
                        [dbo].[StatusRequisicao] e ON a.IdStatusRequisicao = e.IdStatus
                    LEFT JOIN 
                        [dbo].[Operacao] f ON a.IdOperacao = f.IdOperacao
                    LEFT JOIN 
                        [dbo].[HistoricoRequisicao] g ON a.IdRequisicao = g.IdRequisicao AND g.IdRequisicaoHist = (
                            SELECT TOP 1 IdRequisicaoHist 
                            FROM [dbo].[HistoricoRequisicao] 
                            WHERE IdRequisicao = a.IdRequisicao 
                            ORDER BY DataForecast DESC
                        )
                    LEFT JOIN 
                        [dbo].[StatusRequisicaoComentario] h ON g.IdStatusComentario = h.IdStatusComentario
                    LEFT JOIN
                        [dbo].[VisualizacaoArquivo] i ON a.IdRequisicao = i.IdRequisicao AND i.IdUsuario = @UserId
                    WHERE 
                        a.FlagAtiva = 1 and FlagAssumiu = 1";

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId);

                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                RequisicaoInfo requInfo = new RequisicaoInfo
                                {
                                    IdRequisicao = reader.GetInt32(0).ToString(),
                                    NomeRequisicao = reader.GetString(1),
                                    TipoRequisicao = reader.GetString(2),
                                    DataRequisacao = reader.GetDateTime(3).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                                    DataConclusao = reader.IsDBNull(4) ? string.Empty : reader.GetDateTime(4).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                                    IdUsuarioAtendente = reader.IsDBNull(5) ? string.Empty : reader.GetInt32(5).ToString(),
                                    NomeAtendente = reader.GetString(6),
                                    IdUsuarioRequisitante = reader.GetInt32(7).ToString(),
                                    NomeRequisitante = reader.GetString(8),
                                    DescricaoStatus = reader.GetString(9),
                                    Operacao = reader.GetString(10),
                                    UltimoComentario = reader.GetString(11),
                                    StatusComentario = reader.GetString(12),
                                    UltimaVisualizacaoArquivos = reader.IsDBNull(13) ? string.Empty : reader.GetDateTime(13).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                                };
                                ListRequests.Add(requInfo);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle exception
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostVisualizarArquivosAsync([FromForm] int idRequisicao)
        {
            if (idRequisicao == 0)
            {
                return BadRequest(new { message = "IdRequisicao is missing or invalid." });
            }

            string userId = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "IdUsuario")?.Value;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            {
                return BadRequest(new { message = "User ID is missing." });
            }

            string connectionString = "Data Source=...; Initial Catalog=...; User id=...; Password=...!";
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    await connection.OpenAsync();
                    string sql = @"
                IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[VisualizacaoArquivo] WHERE IdRequisicao = @IdRequisicao AND IdUsuario = @UserId)
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE [dbo].[VisualizacaoArquivo]
                    SET DataVisualizacao = @DataVisualizacao
                    WHERE IdRequisicao = @IdRequisicao AND IdUsuario = @UserId
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO [dbo].[VisualizacaoArquivo] (IdRequisicao, IdUsuario, DataVisualizacao)
                    VALUES (@IdRequisicao, @UserId, @DataVisualizacao)
                END";

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataVisualizacao", DateTime.Now);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdRequisicao", idRequisicao);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId);

                        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, new { message = $"An error occurred: {ex.Message}" });
            }

            return new JsonResult(new { success = true });
        }
    }
}

Requisicao.cshtml:
<div class="modal fade" id="andamentosModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="andamentosModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="andamentosModalLabel">Andamentos da Requisição</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="andamentoTab" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link active" id="comentarios-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#comentarios" role="tab" aria-controls="comentarios" aria-selected="true">Comentários</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="arquivos-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#arquivos" role="tab" aria-controls="arquivos" aria-selected="false">
                            Arquivos <span id="arquivoBadge" class="badge bg-danger" style="display: none;">Novo arquivo</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content" id="andamentoTabContent">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="comentarios" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="comentarios-tab">
                        <div class="scrollable-content" style="height: 300px; overflow-y: auto;">
                            <div id="message-container">
                                <!-- Mensagens dinâmicas serão carregadas aqui -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="arquivos" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="arquivos-tab">
                        <div class="scrollable-content" style="height: 300px; overflow-y: auto;">
                            <div id="file-container">
                                <!-- Lista de arquivos será carregada aqui -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="fixed-content w-100">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Carregar arquivo (opcional)</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFile">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Deixe um comentário aqui" id="floatingTextarea2" style="height: 100px"></textarea>
                        <label for="floatingTextarea2">Adicionar um comentário</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="listaStatus">Selecione o status:</label>
                        <select id="statusSelect" class="form-control"></select>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" id="btnInserirComentario" class="btn btn-primary">Inserir Comentário</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#arquivos-tab').on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
        $('#arquivoBadge').hide();

        var selectedData = $('#tabelaRequisicoes').DataTable().row('.selected').data();

        if (selectedData && selectedData.IdRequisicao) {
            var idRequisicao = selectedData.IdRequisicao;

            var postData = {
                idRequisicao: idRequisicao
            };

            console.log("Dados a serem enviados:", postData); // Adicionando log
            var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Request/Requisicao?handler=VisualizarArquivos',
                data: postData,
                headers: {
                    "RequestVerificationToken": token
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("Arquivos marcados como visualizados:", data);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.error("Erro ao marcar arquivos como visualizados:", textStatus, errorThrown);
                    console.error("Response:", jqXHR.responseText); // Adicionando log para a resposta do erro
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.warn("Nenhuma linha selecionada ao tentar marcar arquivos como visualizados.");
        }
    });
</script>

I've tried to update the database when a user views the files and to fetch this information correctly when the page is reloaded. However, the notification badge does not seem to update correctly.
Can anyone help me identify what might be going wrong or suggest any improvements?

Did you checked if your OnPostVisualizarArquivosAsync get hitted while you have seen the file?

Hi, to better solve this problem, I would like to take a closer look at your situation: I'd like to know if at this step in the backend, idRequisicao is able to get the data from the ajax request. You can set a breakpoint to check at public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostVisualizarArquivosAsync([FromForm] int idRequisicao). Also, in the database, you can check whether the record for viewing the file has been successfully updated when you view the file for the second time.

if it's a browser-caching issue (you'd know if breakpoint is not hit on backend when debugging) you need to fire some javascript that calls an endpoint onpageshow.

could be as simple as: window.addEventListener('pageshow', function (event) {
if (event.persisted)
{
location.reload();
} });

Breakpoint Verification:
The OnPostVisualizarArquivosAsync method is triggered correctly when the tab is clicked.
Console Output:
The AJAX call works correctly:
Requisicao:478 Data to be sent: {idRequisicao: '4'}
Requisicao:489 Files marked as viewed: {success: true}
Database Update:
The record is correctly updated in the VisualizacaoArquivo table.
Handling Browser Caching:
Added script to handle caching issues:
window.addEventListener('pageshow', function (event) {
if (event.persisted) {
location.reload();
}
});

Well I try to test but cannot get "shown.bs.tab" triggered.
